# how to add data in ListAdapter?

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-listadapter

In ListAdapter, how can I add data to existing list?

`submitList()` will only replace existing list with new one,
maybe a method to updating data something like this

```
adapter.addNewItem(list)
```

Comment: You need a Diff class to check if the items are the same. Always update the list and only items that changed will be updated, so no need to add new item to the ListAdapter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of modifying data in `ListAdapter`, always update the datasource i.e list in your case and submit the updated list to `ListAdapter`

```
//assume you have this either in your view model or where ever it is
val dataList = ArrayList<String>()

fun updateData(newData: List<Data>){
    dataList.addAll(newData) // add new data to existing data
    adapter.submitList(dataList) //submit the data again
}
```

Comment: do i also need to call notifydatasetchanged / notifyItemRangeInserted like standar recyclerview after calling datalist#addAll?

Comment: no need to do that, submit list will be enough

Comment: to get it work correctly create new refrence from your list to let ListAdapter update the screen `submitList(ArrayList(newData))`

Comment: Be aware that accoding to [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/DiffUtil), `submitList` should be used with a new list. So if you want to append data to a preexisting list, you need to create a copy of it and then append the data.

Comment: @Ricardo Yubal What is best way in Java to copy the list so that the reference in memory is different for the copied list versus the original list?  So that the submitList() method see a difference between the two lists and therefore will proceed to calculcate the difference and update the UI.

Comment: @AJW Can't comment about Java, but in Kotlin `adapter.currentList.toMutableList()` has been enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list from an adapter:

```
adapter.getCurrentList()
```

Then you need to create a copy, add a new item, and submit it to the adapter.

Comment: What is best way in Java to copy the list so that the reference in memory is different for the copied list versus the original list?  So that the submitList() method see a difference between the two lists and therefore will proceed to calculcate the difference and update the UI.